# Jenkins: having problems passing environment variable for use in another job (maybe a bug)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I seem to have found a bug with trying to pass environment variables from one Jenkins job to another.

I have a Jenkins job which contains a Powershell build step. My question is not about the Powershell script, as that does exactly what I want (it goes to Artifactory, finds a list of all the builds and then gets the build number of the latest one). The script ends up with the Artifactory build number as a text string '*$LATEST_BUILD_NO_SLASH*' (for clarity, this is not the Jenkins build number). This is eventually stored as an environment variable called '*LATEST_BUILD_NUM_VAL*'
[image: Powershell code to created env variable]

This is definitely creating an environment variable with my value stored in it, as it can be seen in the 'Environment Variables' list.
[image: Environment Variables list]

This environment variable is passed in the standard way in the parameterized build step.
[image: parameterized build step]

My issue is that when I use this environment variable in a downstream build having passed it using '*LATEST_BUILD_NUM = ${LATEST_BUILD_NUM_VAL*}', I get '*${LATEST_BUILD_NUM_VAL}*' as the value passed to the downstream job:
[image: Latest build number]

But, if I pass a Jenkins created environment variable i.e.'*LATEST_BUILD_NUM = ${JOB_BASE_NAME}*' I get the correct variable in the downstream job:
[image: JOB_BASE_NAME]

I have spent all day banging my head around this and don't really know where to go from here. I seem to be creating the environment variable correctly, as it is in the environment variables list and it works if I use a standard environment variable. I have declared '*LATEST_BUILD_NUM*' as a parameter in my downstream build.

Is there any other way of achieving what I am trying to do?

I have checked in the 'Jenkins Issues' log for [issues with parameterised builds](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39466?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%27parameterized-trigger-plugin%27) and I can't find anything similar to my issue.

In case it is of any relevance, the Jenkins Environment Injector plugin is v2.1.6 and the Parameterized Trigger plugin is v2.35.2.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve in Jenkins Pipeline:

Your second job (JobB) is called from your first job (JobA) as a downstream job. Thus somewhere, (probably the end of your JobA pipeline) you will have:

```
build job: 'CloudbeeFolder1/Path/To/JobB', propagate: false, wait: false, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'MY_PARAM', value: "${env.SOME_VALUE}"]]
```

Then in JobB on the "other side" you have:

```
environment {
    PARAM_FROM_PIPELINE = "${params.MY_PARAM}"
}
```

This gets the value of your parameter into an environment variable in JobB.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately our Jenkins job is part of a much larger non Jenkins pipeline setup, so we cannot convert it just for this.

Answer (score -1):

[image][image]in first job in post build action--> Trigger Parameterized build on other projects select this
In that project build --> give name of downward jobname
select Add parameter in that add Predefined parameter give parameter in key value format e.g Temp=${BUILD_ID}

In second job select project is parameterized in select any option e.g string parameter and put name as Temp and used this parameter in shell or anywhere as $Temp ...

Comment: I tried using this setup but it still doesn't work for me. the value still showup as Temp (Key) with ${Build_ID} as value. Please note, the key=value works for Jenkins env variables. I am trying to use custom variable created by my previous job. Any help is appreciated